# What is wrong with this nested if else program. Print wrong answer whenever the 1st no is greater?.

Tags: javascript, php, html

Give wrong answer every time when i input n1 the greater value as n1=10 n2=3 n2=5. I have tried both type of conditional operator if(n1>=2) & if(n1>n2) but nothing is working in my favor.

```
 <script>
    var n1=prompt("Enter 1st numer");
    var n2=prompt("Enter 2nd numer");
    var n3=prompt("Enter 3rd numer");
    if(n1>n2){
        if(n1>n3){
            document.write(n1+" is greater than "+n2+" and "+n3);
        }
        else{
            document.write(n3+" is greater than "+n1+" and "+n2);
        }
    }
    else{
        if(n2>n3){
            document.write(n2+"is greater than "+n3+"and"+n1);
        }
        else{
            document.write(n3+"is greater than "+n1+" and "+n2);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see any PHP

Comment: You are comparing strings. `prompt` always returns strings. You need to explicitly turn them into numbers.

Comment: @Li357 Errr… nope. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Comparing_strings

Comment: You need to use parseInt() for converting into integer.

Comment: @deceze Oh, I forgot it treats strings specially (which makes sense to compare code units): https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-abstract-relational-comparison

Comment: thanks everyone. that was cheeky mistake